# Outlook API Authentication in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am working into an Outlook integration via Microsoft Graph for our SaaS application. As it stands, my application has basic authentication (username/passsword) and to be able to call the API methods from Microsoft Graph, the user must be signed-in to his Microsoft account and changing authentication methods from the current to AD-driven one may not be an option yet as it'll affect a lot of modules in place.

Is it possible to link the profile to the Microsoft account the user has,
autologging them in and use it to call the API methods - like the style with Facebook & Twitter? If not, how can I be able to call API methods without having them to sign-in everytime the session expires?

Comment: This is far to broad a topic to address here. I'd suggest reading up on the patterns and practices behind OAUTH 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for your scenario:

AD supports a [resource owner credentials grant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) in V1 auth which allows you to authenticate with user credentials. This has some limitations such as lacking support for MFA, and requires you to be very careful about handling user credentials.

Alternatively, you can call into Graph using the V2 [auth client credential flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) in which a tenant admin consents to an application making calls to Graph on behalf of their tenant. Using this flow, your service would also be able to query for resources in Graph without requiring the user to go through the sign-in flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems #2 is one of the options I'll be taking.